# Bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R - \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone provide an example of a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R - \mathbb N$?

Comment: Can you provide one from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: @Siddhant wrong direction, and that's not a bijection

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, why is it so?

Comment: @Siddhant if you mean the map $f:(\Bbb R - \Bbb N) \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x$, then first of all it's a map from $(\Bbb R - \Bbb N)$ to $\Bbb R$, and second of all the map fails to be surjective.

Comment: Voah, I never meant a map from $\mathbb{R-N}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Siddhant well you can't very well have the map $f(x) = x$ go the other way, so it's quite unclear what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $\mathbb{R} = \left( \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z} \right) \cup \color{black}{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N} = \left( \color{black}{\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}} \right) \cup \color{black}{\mathbb{Z^-}}$, so
$$\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$$
becomes
$$\left( \color{green}{\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}} \right) \cup \color{blue}{\mathbb{Z}} \to \left( \color{green}{\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}} \right) \cup \color{red}{\mathbb{Z^-}}$$

Now map all non-integers to itself and send the elements of $\color{blue}{\mathbb{Z}}$ to $\color{red}{\mathbb{Z^-}}$.

Can you find a bijection for this last part? If not, hoover over:

> For example: send the *positive* integers to the **even** negative integers and the *negative* integers to the **odd** negative integers.

Answer (score 6):

Define $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R- \mathbb N$ as follows:

For any non-integer $x$, $f(x) = x$.
For any negative integer $x$, $f(x) = 2x$.
For any non-negative integer $x$, $f(x) = -2x-1$.

Loosely speaking, this will thrust the negative integers into the even negative integers, the non-negative integers into the odd negative integers, and the rest of $\mathbb R$ into itself.